# Modal dialog status invalid after let parent Form set to Enable = true

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 Form, Form1 is a **parent**, Form2 is a **child**.
I need to open form2 by form1, by use modal dialog mode.

Before that I need to get some data, it will take a few second, for lock the application, I use

```
form1.Enable = false;
```

and then I get the data I need to display dialog

```
// this is happened in Form1    
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

for some reason I can't let form1 `Enable=true` before that.
Finally after I finish all thing, then I restore form1

```
form1.Enable = true;
```

**But problem is the modal dialog mode not working anymore. I still can click the form1 UI without not close form2**

For simulate the thing , you can use this code in Fomr1:

```
public Form1()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       new Action(() =>
       {

           // lock the application first
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
           this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               this.Enabled = false;
           }));

           // get data and show form2
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
           this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
           {
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.ShowDialog(this);
           }));

           // after all thing , restore form1
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
           this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               this.Enabled = true;
           }));
       }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```

And then you'll found form2 not displayed as a dialog modal window any more. Is there any way fix it?  Thank you.

Comment: This is a normal mishap, you'll have to set the form's Enabled property back to *true* before you show the dialog.  Do note that this generally behaves very poorly, you are liable to lose the foreground since there won't be another window in your app that can get the focus.  Consider disabling a panel or whatever control that shouldn't be used instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, I know that's normal. But I need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the `Form` it is `Dispose`d and should not be shown again. If you want to show it again, `Hide` it instead.

Comment: I'm so sorry, because of my mistake, I write `Visible`, the correct property is `Enable`

Comment: Why do you set `Enabled=false` on `Form1`

Comment: Before get the data and display `Form2`, I need lock the application, don't let user click any other place.

Comment: ShowDialog will lock the rest of the application and there is no need to manually lock it.